# cygwin-perl enable multithreading

Tags: multithreading, perl, cygwin

I am using perl version 5.22 with cygwin. I am not able to figure out the problem in the following code. It looks like  multi threading is not enable or something. When I ran the following code it just terminated without any message.

```
use warnings;
use threads;

sub threaded_task {

    threads -> create(sub { 

        print "Starting thread\n";
        sleep(2);
        print "Ending thread\n";


    });
 }

while(1) {
threaded_task("arjun");
print "main thread\n";
sleep (2); 
}
```

64 bit config :
[image]

32 bit config: 
[image]

Comment: How did you run the code?

Comment: Using cygwin terminal by typing : perl filename.pl

Comment: Do other perl scripts work OK? Your script works correctly for me on Linux (no cygwin machine at hand).

Comment: Yes all the other scripts which do not use threading work correctly.

Comment: I came upon something called "Dusethreads" which enable multithreaded perl in cygwin. But not sure how to configure it.  https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/perl/pod/perlcygwin.asp

Comment: Also quite strange that the code work in 32 bit version of cygwin but not in 64 bit. I check four machines , two having 32 bit and two 64 bit.

Comment: `Dusethreads` is a compile option for Perl. But without thread support, Perl should tell you when you try `use threds`.

Comment: There is another option : Duse64bitint. Looks like those are the basic difference between 32 and 64 bit (Please check image at the top). Do you know how to set those options.

Comment: You set them when compiling the Perl binary. But it seems threads should work in both. Is your machine 64 bit?

Comment: yes it is 64 bit.

Comment: What is `echo $?` after you execute the script?

Comment: How is it done @ikegami

Comment: Execute `echo $?` after running your script. What's the output?

Comment: So after executing perl script through cygwin terminal (it terminated) , i type echo $? in the cygwin terminal again and it return 0.

Comment: If it died from a protection fault (segfault), I would have expected that to be non-zero. But this is cygwin, a unix environment running on Windows. Windows doesn't have signals, so I'm not sure what happens when there's a protection violation.

Comment: I don't know what else to say. That code should not crash, and I can't reproduce the problem. You don't wait for the thread to end, but it should at least output `main thread`. You could try uninstall and reinstalling `perl` -- maybe one of the files got corrupted. Other than that, you're left debugging your executable (using `gdb`?).

Comment: I will point out that your title is nonsense. As you showed, both of your `perl` have threads "enabled".

Comment: @ikegami But strange that the same code work on some of the machine .

Comment: What do you mean by "works on some of the machine"?

Comment: I installed cygwin on various machine. It is working in couple of machine but not all. Like you said both perl have threads "enabled", but it works in only one of them .

Comment: It's not weird at all that it works on some of the machines. It should work.

Comment: I bet it should work. But could not figure out what is the problem.

Comment: I can't debug `perl` for you; it works on my machine.